# Shading of Dataset area

Tags: matrix, dataset, style

I want to shade a certain rectangular subarea of a `Dataset`:

```
dt =
  <|"fra" -> <|"19" -> 2359, "20" -> 2181, "21" -> 2321, "22" -> 2378|>,
   "gre" -> <|"19" -> 184, "20" -> 167, "21" -> 181, "22" -> 192|>,
   "ita" -> <|"19" -> 1729, "20" -> 1574, "21" -> 1684, "22" -> 1745|>,
   "por" -> <|"19" -> 200, "20" -> 184, "21" -> 194, "22" -> 207|>,
   "spa" -> <|"19" -> 1193, "20" -> 1058, "21" -> 1117, "22" -> 1177|>|>;
```

Find subarea positions via row and column keys:

```
py = Flatten @ Position[Keys @ dt[[1]], y_ /; MatchQ[y, "20" | "21" | "22"]];
pc = Flatten @ Position[Keys @ dt, c_ /; MatchQ[c, "ita" | "por"]];
pp = Flatten[Outer[List, pc, py], 1];

bg = pp /. x : {_, _} :> x -> GrayLevel[0.9]
```

[image]

```
Dataset[dt, Alignment -> Right, ItemSize -> 5, Background -> bg]
```

[image]

This didn't work!

```
mx = dt // Normal // Values // Map[Values];
```

Only after removing the row and column headers the shaded subarea appears:

```
Dataset[mx, Alignment -> Right, ItemSize -> 5, Background -> bg]
```

[image]

How can I get this result with row and column headers as a `Dataset`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Dataset[dt, Alignment -> Right,
 Background -> {{"ita" | "por", "20" | "21" | "22"} -> GrayLevel[.9]}]
```

[image]

**See:** [Christopher Carlson, New 12.1 Dataset Interactive Controls and Formatting Options](https://blog.wolfram.com/2020/06/23/new-12-1-dataset-interactive-controls-formatting-options/)

Comment: I wouldn't have found this solution - even after looking at the cited reference. Thank you.

Comment: You are most welcome @eldo. I also recently learned from this blog  that, in versions 12.1+,   styling options for `Dataset`work just like `Grid`.